# Floor leveling compound ontop of glued-down laminate

Tags: flooring, floor, subfloor, laminate-floor

There is floating LVP currently installed in my kitchen which needs to be replaced. Underneath it is glued-down laminate.

There is a small section of the floor that dips down that I would like to level if possible. Can I apply floor leveling compound ontop of the glued down tiles?

Comment: Do you mean a glued down Vinyl? or linoleum? The exact product may have bearing on the answer.

Comment: I think it's linoleum, it seems pretty hard - harder than vinyl.

Answer (score 1):

SLC is typically rated for install overtop of L/360 floors.  Assuming your glued down laminate is well adhered to the substrate below it and that substrate is a minimum of 1.25" thick (almost no wood floors are), then the SLC would be approved for that purpose.  The two SLC I am most familiar with are Sika and Mapei.

I've installed SLC on 5/8" tng plywood using the wood primer.  The SLC generally develops hairline cracks but as long as it doesn't allow deflection and pieces of it can't delaminate and migrate under pieces of the flooring causing noise then you should be ok.  If you are installing underlayment on top of the SLC then noise is less likely.

One trick often employed is to get a stiffer underlay and add an extra piece to this area.  It depends what the height difference is.  Or you can use door skin or a combination of the two.

The best approach depends on your budget, how picky you are for your floors being quiet / flat and the install method for the new floor.